# Joomla 3.0 Insert Read More line not working

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

The read-more-line needs to be on it’s own line but even after doing this it seemed that the WYSIWYG editor puts code into the code:

`<hr id=”system-readmore” />` was being changed to `<hr id=”\&quot;system-readmore\&quot;” />`
You may also be experiencing other issues with quotes in Joomla, the cause is Magic Quotes. Joomla 3 requires magic quotes to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file ad the following code to it’s own line:

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

Answer (score 1):

In article manager toggle editor to the code, you may find this code

if you do change to following by deleting class=""

hope it works